# Google Sheets node.js api gives an error "Unhandled promise rejection" when attempting to output changed spreadsheet data to console

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

```
function checkForChanges() {
    let spreadsheetId = '1oHNELBZ3zV4PQBVsJrtqX4Cz00IFmJG_2SaJ4bgTa3c'
    let ranges = ['A2:P2', 'A3:P3', 'A4:P4', 'A5:P5']
    this.batchGet ({
        spreadsheetId,
        ranges, 
        }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(`${result.valueRanges.length} ranges retrieved.`);
            } 

    })
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    while (true) {
        checkForChanges();
    }
});
```

I'm expecting that when I change something on the spreadsheet that it returns in console with what was changed. but instead I get this error when i run the program:

```
[nodemon] starting `node --inspect turnip_bot.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/b52c6ec8-70cb-451a-9b70-fc8bada920fc
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
(node:1200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.batchGet is not a function
    at checkForChanges (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\turnip_bot.js:72:7)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\turnip_bot.js:87:3)
    at Client.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:433:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:417:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:199:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:466:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:438:16)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
(node:1200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1200) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I took the code off of the google sheets API quickstart and edited it slightly for my use case and used some of the documentation to help with reading the spreadsheet on mutiple rows.

If I run the sample it returns:

```
[nodemon] starting `node --inspect google_sheets_api_sample.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/04ef1aed-3c10-40e5-b8f2-78782b5537bc
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
(node:3208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: authentication failed
    at authorize (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\google_sheets_api_sample.js:57:11)
    at main (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\google_sheets_api_sample.js:13:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programing\Node.js\Discord-Turnip-Bot\google_sheets_api_sample.js:42:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
(node:3208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3208) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you follow the sample of Node.js of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)?

Comment: Also, does it work for you if you assign `ranges` only one range? `let ranges = ['A2:P2']`

Comment: what is `this` here?

Comment: @ziganotschka i just put it at the bottom of the post. it still gives an error. and no it doesn't work with only one range.

Comment: What I meant is that you follow the syntax analogous to the quickstart rather than incorporating different approaches like e.g. the `this` as pointed out by theMaster.